# Genes associated with human female breast size

Tags: human-anatomy, human-genetics

What are the genes associated with female breast size and natural variation thereof in human beings?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This seems like a valid question to me, but please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, we encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). The lack of evidence in your post for any effort at prior research may be why some people have downvoted your post. Thanks! 

Answer (score 2):

It's frequently helpful to do a little research with e.g. Google before asking questions here. I searched ["human breast size genetics"](https://www.google.com/search?q=human%20breast%20size%20genetics&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS695US695&oq=human%20breast%20size%20genetics&aqs=chrome..69i57.5171j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and found a lot of information.

Also note that in genetics it is usually misleading to say "the genes for X" or similar constructions. We can point to specific genetic variants (e.g. DNA variations, which are not genes) that have a statistical association with some phenotype (such as breast size). This is the best we can do here.

To directly answer your question, looking at some of the papers there is not strong evidence for any specific gene being associated with breast size. The total proportion of variation explained by all the variants detected is on the order of 2%-3%. In other words, those genes don't seem to be very important for breast size. You can read more about these variants [here](https://jmg.bmj.com/content/50/10/666.short) or [here](https://bmcmedgenet.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2350-13-53), and in other similar papers that you can find on google scholar.

Some (such as those papers) have estimated that variation in breast size is up to 50% due to genetics, which is to say that "heritability" is 30%-50%. Some people interpret this to mean that we just need to look harder to find more variants. However heritability is a notoriously unreliable estimator, so it may be truly a much smaller percentage of breast size variation that is heritable. To read more about how to interpret this try [this paper](https://icds.uoregon.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/wells-and-stock-2011-TEM-reexamining-heritability.pdf).

Hope that helps.